# How to use PDO with dependency injection?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, dependencies, constructor-injection

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use dependency injection. I've read over a lot of questions/answers here but I can't picture it with the code I'm using.

Model.php

```
abstract class Model {

    protected static function getDB() {
        static $db = null;

        if ($db === null) {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8', 'dbuser', 'password');
        }

        return $db;
    }
}
```

The model.php just contains that function, which I want to move away from setting and calling it **statically**.

User.php

```
class User extends Model {

    /*
    * Selects all of the user information
    */
    public function getUser($id){

        $db = static::getDB();

        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id');
        $sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();

        return $sth->fetch();
    }

    /*
    * Selects all of the user posts
    */
    public function getUserPosts($id){
        $db = static::getDB();

        $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user_posts WHERE user_id = :id');
        $sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();

        return $sth->fetch();
    }
}
```

In the user.php I'm extending the model class, but I have set the `$db = static::getDB();` in every single function.

I know that dependency injection is pretty much just passing the methods/variables to an object but I'm not even sure I'm doing this right.

**Updated with further thoughts:**

I'm thinking it would be better to create a private variable, and in the constructor we'd just call the `getDB()` like so:

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->db = getDB();
    }

    /*
    * example usage
    */
    public function getUser($id){
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id');
        $sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();

        return $sth->fetch();
    }
}
```

But would it still count as dependency injection as I'm not calling the class directly in the function constructor?

**SECOND UPDATE:**
After reading multiple guides, and this [page](http://coderoncode.com/dependency-injection/design-patterns/programming/php/development/2014/01/06/dependency-injection-php.html) which wound up making a lot more sense, this is what I came up with.

model.php

```
abstract class Model {
    protected $db = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if($this->db === null){
            try {
                $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . Config::DB_NAME . '; charset=utf8', Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Model $db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    /*
    * example usage
    */
    public function getUser($id){
        $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id');
        $sth->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sth->execute();

        return $sth->fetch();
    }
}
```

How does that look?

Comment: The beauty of dependency injection is that your class doesn't have to know, for example, what is being used for storage.  You could pass it a mysql db object, or a postgres db object, or who knows what.  But that only happens if you pass the object into the constructor.  `public function __construct($dbObject) { $this->db = new $dbObject; }`  Granted, I'm not talking about static objects (which I stay away from), but it still stands to reason that to have dependency *injection*, you have to actually *inject* it.

Comment: You are not using DI

Comment: @OsDev I've updated the question with further information

Comment: @TimMorton I've updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are not using Dependency Injection because you are not actually supplying any dependencies into your Model, you are generating them on the constructor.

In order to supply the dependency you should pass it as an argument to the constructor:

```
public function __construct($db){
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

This way you decouple the creation of the connection from your Class and you can use the benefits of Dependency Injection, like passing a Mock object for testing instead of the actual thing.

Comment: After taking a look at your answer I started searching around more, how does the updated question look now?

Comment: @Johnson Why does `User` extend `Model`?  You're passing in Model through DI in the constructor.  All the goodness of Model is now available through `$this->db`.  But now, there's the question of instantiated vs static, which I'm not familiar with...

Comment: @TimMorton Model is just the PDO connection, I'm just trying to create 1 connection for the user class or any other classes that extends the Model class. You're saying that since I already extended the Model class I don't need to inject it in the user construct?

Comment: No, just the opposite.  By extending, you're locking User to that particular Model, which makes your code rigid.  Suppose you want to change to a different database, or you want to use sqlite for testing... With DI, you pass in whatever you want to use.  (preferably, it would be an abstraction that lets you use your own defined methods, so that your User class would be agnostic of any database commands.)  But if you extend a particular model, you're stuck with that one.

Comment: @TimMorton That makes sense a lot more sense as well. Thank you, I'll think of how I can restructure my code because right now I'm calling my User class from various files, and if I inject the PDO into the user construct `__construct(Model $db)`, in other files where i call the user class ex: `$user = new User();` it keeps asking me to pass an argument, that part has me confused since the connection information is already stated in the model class.